# QWidget::repaint() skipped by "sticked" flag Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled

Tags: qt, qwidget, paintevent

So, situation:

`Qt 4.8.4`, `MSVS 2012`.

I have six `QToolButton` inside `QWidget` (this `QWidget` is inside another `QWidget` ), `QToolButtons` located in `QHBoxLayout`.

When I quickly press left mouse button on one of `QToolButton`, then move mouse out of `QToolButton` and release mouse button on top parent `QWidget` 5 or more times. With some probability `QToolButton` look normal, but in other states(hover, press) it's not repainted.

Searching `QTBUG` - no result.

`QToolButton` still emit clicked, pressed, released and else signals, but not repainted.
Some searching in `Qt` source code and debugging give some information:

I inherit `QToolButton`, `reimlement enterEvent`, `leaveEvent`, `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, `paintEvent`.

`enterEvent`, `leaveEvent`, `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` - still working.
`paintEvent` - ignored.

Adding update or repaint in `enterEvent`, `leaveEvent`, `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`: no effect.

Then I use break pintsm, and find:  in `QWidget::repaint(const QRect &rect)` checking flags and `updatesEnabled()` is return false then called return from repaint !!! O_O ok, go inside `updatesEnabled()`.

```
inline bool QWidget::updatesEnabled() const
{ return !testAttribute(Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled); }
```

This is mean `Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled` is set true.

Qt Assistant :
**`Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled`** *Indicates that updates are blocked (including the system background). This flag is set or cleared by the Qt kernel.*

Hmmmmm... 
We have another flag **`Qt::WA_ForceUpdatesDisabled`** and it we can change:

Indicates that updates are explicitly disabled for the widget; i.e. It will remain disabled even when all its ancestors are set to the updates-enabled state. This implies `WA_UpdatesDisabled`. This is set/cleared by `QWidget::setUpdatesEnabled()`.

Inside `setUpdatesEnabled()` attribute `Qt::WA_UpdatesDisabled` is changing

Using `QWidget::setUpdatesEnabled()` still has no effect.

I know, this use-case not usual for `QToolButton`, and I don't try drag and drop. I mean simple sequence: `mousePress` - `mouseMove` - `mouseRelease`.

What some advice?

Comment: You'd need to prepare a self-contained test case for this using the Qt test framework, so that no human has to click anywhere, and submit it as a Qt bug - assuming that you succeed in reproducing this problem.